# Getting at javascript values where a range is the index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, range

I'm probably going about this in entirely the wrong way, but pseudocode-wise, this is what I'd like to do:

```
ranges = new Array([0 - 400] = 'dog',
               [401 - 1000] = 'cat',
               [1001 - 1233] = 'rat');

alert(ranges[243]);
```

and magically get 'dog' pop up on my screen. Now, I'm well aware you can't do something that simple, but I have absolutely no idea how to do something like this (without looping through an array, performing a > and < on a value etc..)

Any ideas? :)

Comment: You could write your own prototype for that which handles multiple arrays itself and hides this away from the user. (user meant as the dev who uses your stuff)

Comment: Not a poor example at all, i totally misread :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is very simple and straightforward - though it assumes that you don't want "holes" in your ranges. No error handling in this example, but essentially you just need to pass upper bounds, lower bounds are implicit.

```
function test() {
    var array = MakeRangeArray([500,1000,2000], ['dog', 'cat', 'rat']);

    alert (array[243]);
    alert (array[500]);
    alert (array[501]);
}

function MakeRangeArray(upperBounds, values) {
   var rangeArray = new Array(upperBounds[upperBounds.length-1]);

   var idx = 0;
   for (var i=0; i < rangeArray.length; i++) {
      if (i > upperBounds[idx]) {
        idx++;
      }
      rangeArray[i] = values[idx];
   }
   return rangeArray;
}
```

Comment: All really good answers, but I had to give this one the tick as it's what I needed (don't need 'holes'!) I did mod up all others, thanks guys.

Comment: My ranges actually go up into the millions, is this a waste of memory doing it this way? Will it slow/mess up old browsers/old computers?

Comment: Well, 50,000 but could go into the millions in the future

Comment: Yes, if your array size goes up into the millions, this is probably a spectacularly bad idea; especially if your internal ranges are large. What you might do is create a custom 'class' that incorporates the logic from the answer by @jfriend000.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could populate a simple array with all the duplicates:

```
var i,
    ranges = [];

for (i = 0; i <= 400; i++) ranges[i] = "dog";
for (i = 401; i <= 1000; i++) ranges[i] = "cat";
for (i = 1001; i <= 1233; i++) ranges[i] = "rat";

alert(ranges[243]); // "dog"
```

A more sensible option might be to use some kind of data structure that actually holds the low and high values of each range:

```
var ranges = [
  { "low" : 0, "high" : 400, "animal" : "dog" },
  { "low" : 401, "high" : 1000, "animal" : "cat" },
  { "low" : 1001, "high" : 1233, "animal" : "rat" }
];

function getAnimal(index) {
   for (var i=0; i < ranges.length; i++)
      if (ranges[i].low <= index && ranges[i].high >= index)
         return ranges[i].animal;

   return "Out of range"; // or could leave it to return undefined
}

alert(getAnimal(243)); // "dog"
alert(getAnimal(100000)); // "Out of range"
```

Or you could combine the two approaches: pass the ranges data structure with the low and high values to a function that uses the information to populate another array as per the first approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could fully populate an array sp you can dp a direct index into the array at run-time.  Once the original data structure is created, that will be fast at run-time, but not very storage efficient.  I generally wouldn't recommend this, but to build the array:

```
var ranges = [
    {min: 0, max: 400, value: 'dog'},
    {min: 401, max: 1000, value: 'cat'},
    {min: 1001, max: 1233, value: 'rat'}
];

var lookupArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    // make sure array is big enough
    lookupArray.length = Math.max(lookupArray.length, ranges[i].max);
    for (var j = ranges[i].min, j <= ranges[i].max; j++) {
        lookupArray[j] = ranges[i].value;
    }
}

// function to find the value for a given index
function findValue(index) {
    return(lookupArray[index]);
}
```

Or, in a more compact structure, you can use a data structure and function like this:

```
var ranges = [
    {min: 0, max: 400, value: 'dog'},
    {min: 401, max: 1000, value: 'cat'},
    {min: 1001, max: 1233, value: 'rat'}
];

function findValue(index) {
    var range;
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        range = ranges[i];
        if (index >= range.min && index <= range.max) {
            return(range.value);
        }
    }
}

alert(findValue(402));    // 'cat'
```

You could also use a straight array with implicit positions in the array (code and data are a little more compact, but both are a bit less readable):

```
var ranges = [
    0, 400, 'dog',
    401, 1000, 'cat',
    1001, 1233, 'rat'
];

function findValue(index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i+=3) {
        if (index >= ranges[i] && index <= ranges[i+1]) {
            return(ranges[i+2];
        }
    }
}
```